# Adding fields dynamically in JQuery-Jtable

Tags: jquery-jtable

How can I add fields dynamically in Jtable. I want to have multiple values for Cities
Please Refer the image attached

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is not built-in with jQuery jTable. To deal with this I've created a script for the same purpose. This handles (a) adding more controls OR group of controls and (b) remove control(s).

Here is the script:

```
//add '.add_more' class to
$(".add_more").on('click', function () {

    // creates unique id for each element
    var _uniqueid_ = +Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
    var new_ele_id = $(this).attr("data-clone-target") + _uniqueid_;

    var cloneObj = $("#" + $(this).attr("data-clone-target"))
    .clone()
    .val('')
    .attr("id", new_ele_id);

    // if the control is grouped control
    if ($(this).hasClass('group_control') == true) {
        $($(cloneObj).children()).each(function () {
            $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id") + _uniqueid_).val("");
        });
    }

    $(cloneObj).insertBefore($(this));

    //creates a 'remove' link for each created element or grouped element
    $("<a href='javascript:void(0);' class='remove_this' data-target-id='" + new_ele_id + "'></a>")
    .on('click', function () {
        if ($(this).is(":visible") == true) {
            if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
                $("#" + $(this).attr("data-target-id")).remove();
                $(this).remove();
            }
        }
        else {
            $("#" + $(this).attr("data-target-id")).remove();
            $(this).remove();
        }

    }).insertBefore($(this));
    $("#" + new_ele_id).focus();



});

//remove element script
$(".remove_this").on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).is(":visible") == true) {
        if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
            $("#" + $(this).attr("data-target-id")).remove();
            $(this).remove();
        }
    }
    else {
        $("#" + $(this).attr("data-target-id")).remove();
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

**Usage: Single Element**  http://jsfiddle.net/vkscorpion1986/ktbn4qLg/2/

```
<input class="" id="<ELEMENT-ID>" type="text" name="input1">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-clone-target="<ELEMENT-ID>" title="Add More" class="add_more">Add More</a>
```

**Usage: Grouped Elements** http://jsfiddle.net/vkscorpion1986/ktbn4qLg/4/

```
<div id="<ELEMENT-ID>">
    <input class="" id="input1" type="text" name="input1">
    <input class="" id="input2" type="text" name="input2">
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-clone-target="<ELEMENT-ID>" title="Add More" class="add_more group_control">Add More</a>
```

**attributes**

```
href = javascript:void(0); // just to disable the anchor tag default behaviour 
data-clone-target = id of the target element
```

**css classes**

```
.add_more = to implement the add more/remove controls functionality
.group_control  = for indicating that this is group of elements which have to be repeted
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not made with jTable. You can use input option (http://jtable.org/ApiReference#fopt-input) and this: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple Or you can create your own dialog.